# Regular expressions and Unicode in Python: difference between sub and findall

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am having difficulty trying to figure out a bug in my Python (2.7) script. I am getting an difference with using sub and findall in recognizing special characters.

Here is the code:

```
>>> re.sub(ur"[^-' ().,\w]+", '' , u'Castañeda', re.UNICODE)
u'Castaeda'
>>> re.findall(ur"[^-' ().,\w]+", u'Castañeda', re.UNICODE)
[]
```

When I use findall, it correctly sees ñ as an alphabetic character, but when I use sub it replaces this--treating it as a non-alphabetic character.

I've been able to get the correct functionality using findall with string.replace, but this seems like a bad solution. Also, I want to use re.split, and I'm having the same problems as with re.sub.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Which version are you using? It works just fine on 2.7.1

Comment: ActivePython 2.7.1.4 based on Python 2.7.1. Thanks for letting me know that it worked fine for you. There might be a problem with my install... I just tried it on Python 2.6.4, which is on also my machine, and I'm getting the same problem

Comment: I tested it from the console on ubuntu 11.04. Started with LANG=en_GB.UTF-8, no LC entries.

Comment: I'm on windows xp. I get the correct functionality with python 3.2 (after I remove the unicode flag in front of the string).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call signature of `re.sub` is:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0)
```

So

```
re.sub(ur"[^-' ().,\w]+", '' , u'Castañeda', re.UNICODE)
```

is setting `count` to `re.UNICODE`, which has value 32.

Try instead:

```
In [57]: re.sub(ur"(?u)[^-' ().,\w]+", '', u'Castañeda')
Out[57]: u'Casta\xf1eda'
```

Placing `(?u)` at the beginning of the regex is an alternate way to specify the `re.UNICODE` flag in the regex itself. You can also set the other flags 
`(?iLmsux)` this way. (For more info click [this link](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) and search for "(?iLmsux)".)

Similarly, the call signature of `re.split` is:

```
re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0)
```

The solution is the same.

Comment: In case you want to use unicode character property (like `\p{L}`) you have to know that `re` doesn't support it.  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex does.